# What is the session time out for GCP Console sessions and how do I change it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity, google-workspace

We are authenticating to GCP via GSuite, and we have set the session timeout to 1 hour (the lowest).

I have signed out of GSuite to ensure the correct period is set, and I can now see that my Google Identity times out for services other than GCP.  However, when I go back to the GCP project, the session is still valid and does not seem to require re-authorisation.

What is the default session time out in GCP compared to the Google Identity time out, and more importantly, can this be set to a small period such as 1 hour?

Answer (score 0):

I have found [related question in Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/808969/google-cloud-platform-is-there-a-way-to-protect-deleting-instance-with-2fa/809151#809151) which has already been answered. Quoting the answer below

> " At the moment there is a [feature request](https://serverfault.com/questions/808969/google-cloud-platform-is-there-a-way-to-protect-deleting-instance-with-2fa/809151#809151) to allow the session
>   timeout of your Google Cloud Console.
>
> The Console asks for confirmation before deleting instances but
>   [2-Step verification](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=312) is only enforced when you sign in from a new
>   device (you can choose to have this device remembered for 30 days).
>
> As a workaround you might be able to use [3rd party tools](https://www.google.ca/landing/2step/) to force
>   the sign out".

Answer (score 0):

The timeout feature is available now. BTW, it's the absolute length of session duration (whether idle or not), not **idle** timeout. See this blog:

- [Introducing time-bound Session Length defaults to improve your security posture](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/improve-security-posture-with-time-bound-session-length)

This comment can shed more light on a related feature:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904790#comment36